# Merge sub arrays and keep field name as a value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document like below;

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "data": {
      "status": {
        "COMPLETED": [
          {
            "count": 1.0,
            "assignee": "ABC"
          },
          {
            "count": 1.0,
            "assignee": "DEF"
          }
        ],
        "OPEN": [
          {
            "count": 5.0,
            "assignee": "XYZ"
          },
          {
            "count": 5.0,
            "assignee": "PQR"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Expected aggregated result:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "data": {
      "status": [
        {
          "count": 1.0,
          "assignee": "ABC",
          "value": "COMPLETED"
        },
        {
          "count": 1.0,
          "assignee": "DEF",
          "value": "COMPLETED"
        },
        {
          "count": 5.0,
          "assignee": "XYZ",
          "value": "OPEN"
        },
        {
          "count": 5.0,
          "assignee": "PQR",
          "value": "OPEN"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The document fields "COMPLETED / OPEN" became a value for a new field "value" and the sub arrays got merged in the result. How can I write an aggregation query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to convert your sub-fields into an array of keys and values. Then you need [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) and [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to add a new field (`value`) and [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to flatten an array of arrays:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            "data.status": {
                $reduce: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$data.status" },
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                            "$$value",
                            { $map: { input: "$$this.v", as: "v", in : { $mergeObjects: [ "$$v", { value: "$$this.k" } ] } } }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Twcuw_vhzvo)